# No such device or address windows

Tags: windows, errno, ace

When I used ACE_OS::fopen function to create file for writing, the result was failed and got errno message "No such device or address". Windows OS: windows server 2008 r2 enterprise! It made me confused, what kinds of reasons could cause this problem!

Answer (score 0):

You are not posting any code, so we can't tell for sure, but there could be multiple reasons:
 1. The file is not there
 2. You specify the path not correctly
 3. You do not have permission to read the file

Comment: if(NULL == this->fp_)
{
  FILE* fp = ACE_OS::fopen(this->fileName_.c_str(), "a+b");
  if(NULL == fp)
  {
    LOGERR("Open file[%s] for writting failed, system errmsg[%s]", this->fileName_.c_str(), strerror(errno));
    return NULL;
  }

  this->fp_ = fp;
}

Comment: that's piece of my code! Just so simple! It made depressed!

Comment: And what is the value of fileName_, what are the exact security settings of that file on disk?

Comment: the value of fileName_ is the file path to be created! Thank  you for your kindness!

Comment: It will only create the file, not the full path as far as I know